# Navigation Controller Transparent Bar Style is not working

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am using a navigation controller, and I have the style set to :

```
navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

But when I run my program, the navigation controller looks like it is on top of a white background, not my background. When I push a controller, left or right, all my view, the current one, shifts to the top exactly the size of the navigation bar. And it is there where I can see my background through the navigation controller bar. Any ideas? When my barStyle is  set to opaque, everything looks fine. I was thinking on setting my view frame a negative 'y' value, but I think there should a more elegant way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the UINavigationController assumes that your controller view frames don't include the area beneath the navigation bar.

UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent is more often used for UIToolbar, so Apple probably didn't make it easy to use it nicely with UINavigationBar. You'll probably need to abandon the UINavigationController, or start hacking the frames (careful with rotations), if you want to reliably render under the bar area.

Also, if your intention is to hide the navigation bar after a few seconds, you'll have a **much** easier time if you make it fade out (like the Photos app) instead of trying to slide it up (like Mobile Safari). Trust me on that one... that took me a *lot* of time to learn the hard way.

Comment: This is not the case in iOS 5 & 6. Check my answer below with transparent image and translucent = YES which allows the content to flow below the bar.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use a transparent background image, and translucent = YES to allow the content to flow below the bar. Works on iOS 5 / 6. Add in viewDidLoad.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
UIImage * backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"spacer.gif"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I attached the spacer.gif image here, a single 1px x 1px transparent image.

[image: spacer.gif]

Comment: Old question, but on xcode 6 this works the best for me

Answer (score 4):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.169 green:0.373 blue:0.192 alpha:0.9];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Note:

1. Don't use `self.navigationBarStyle` and `self.navigationBarTintColor` to change.
2. Add the last two statements to your `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem (in 3.1.3) and while you can't set the bar style after the navigationBar has already been setup you CAN set the tintColor and translucent values whenever you like:

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Will create the 'blackTranslucent' bar, I change the navigationBar look when I push certain view controllers onto the stack.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by making the background of the root view the same as my view. The white area behind the navigation bar turned out to be the root view.

Answer (score 1):

The navigation controller offsets the coordinate sytem of all it's subviews so they draw below the navigation bar.

Extend your view's frame into the negative y domain for it to draw under the navigation bar.

Comment: Tried this, with no luck. I will continue testing, as this seems to be the obvious way.

Comment: This doesn't work because UINavigationController *really* wants to manage the size of views it manages on it's own, so it tends to reset frames at will. You can try resetting the frame of the view you intend to slide under *after* that view is on screen, but Your Mileage May Vary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the barstyle in your info.plist file for it offset everything correctly.

However, I haven't tried it since the 2.1 f/w was released, but when I tried this in 2.0 I found that the setting was lost after a rotation from portrait to landscape.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this, may be it will helpful.

```
_topToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
_topToolBar.alpha = 0.3;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem.I solved!

```
ImageViewExtendController *detailImageController = [[ImageViewExtendController alloc] init];  
[detailImageController loadImage:url];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailImageController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set your nav controller's navigationBar to transparent in your App delegate early enough (It worked for me before adding the nav controller to the window), it will automatically shift your view up underneath the navigation bar.

Unfortunately it does not also shift your view underneath the status bar. Sad, it looks like you need to implement your own version of UINavigationController. Luckily, it's not too bad as UINavigationBar is pretty reusable.

Comment: Well, maybe the solution is that, implement my own version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Extend Edges options in child viewControllers

As for example, in xcode editor, go to your first viewcontroller child and unset the options:

```
Extend Edges;
    Under Top Bars;
    Under Bottom Bars;
    Under Opaque Bars;
```

This way your child ViewController will not layout starting below the status bar of the navigation controller, neither the tabbar or the toolbars

hope it may help anyone