# Child UIView underneath the translucent bar of UINavigationController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

The root view of my UINavigationViewController sits nicely underneath the the translucent nav bar. However when I push child views, they get aligned below the nav bar. How come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UINavigationController's view has its origin below the navbar, most likely to make sure the controller always works the same way. Maybe this'll help:
[Navigation Controller Transparent Bar Style is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228319/navigation-controller-transparent-bar-style-is-not-working)

Comment: Seems like it. I did not find a way to make this work with UINavigationController, so ended up implementing it manually.