# remove translucent bar in navigation bar created with storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I created a navigationController from the storyboard and now i'm trying to remove it's translucent option

I've put this on my appdelegate.m

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:52.0/255 green:152.0/255 blue:219.0/255 alpha:1]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

But this is crashing my app with a nonsense error, so I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

I have found this similar question but didn't solved my problem:
[Navigation Controller Transparent Bar Style is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228319/navigation-controller-transparent-bar-style-is-not-working)

But I'm not sure how to do that because I don't have a variable navController since I created my navigationController from the storyboard. How can I call the storyboard navigation controller programmatically and do something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this to `viewDidLoad` on the first view controller appearing on the navigation stack:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

Comment: blake305 do you know how I could change the status bar style as well?

Comment: Please elaborate a little in a new question :)

Comment: UIBarStyleBlackOpaque is "deprecated" according to apple

Answer (score 13):

If you designed your view with a storyboard then you can solve the problem using XCode. Select the NavigationBar widget and uncheck "Translucent".

[image: XCode 5]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use storyboard, but IB, set the navigation bar style in MainWindow.xib to NOT translucent and set as color not the clear color.