# when navigationBar.isTranslucent is true, the backgroundImage of navigationbar become translucent too

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

In my first page, the navigation bar should be transparent, and when push to next page, the navigation bar should be a image. I worked it out by changing the `_UIBarBackground` or `_UINavigationBarBackground`'s alpha.

But I meet a big problem, in the first page, view should be placed and draw from (0,0) so I set the navigation bar's `isTranslucent` to `true`, that all works fine. But when I enter the next page, background image shows with a translucent looking which I don't want.

btw, I set background using:

```
navVC.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "navigation_bar_background"),
                                       for: .default)
```

[image]

I checked the image used here, and it's not translucent.

What can I do with this issue? I don't want set viewController's `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` to true due to ugly appearance when animation.

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17130171/3901620

Answer (score 0):

Combination of these 2 solutions will help.

http://ioscodeguide.blogspot.in/2014/01/navigation-bar-bagground-image.html

http://ioscodeguide.blogspot.in/2014/01/navigation-bar-font-style-and-font.html

---

**In first view:**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

---

**In 2nd view:**

Set image to your navigationBar using the following link.

[How to set Navigation Bar Bagground image - By - *iOSCodeGUIDE*](http://ioscodeguide.blogspot.in/2014/01/navigation-bar-bagground-image.html)

---

Adding to that
To keep navigation bar transparent in first page and display on 2nd page,

1st Page viewwill appear Hide-Yes  NavigationBarHide, and on view did disappear Hide-No